# nvm node version install issue in windows 10

Tags: node.js, windows-10, git-bash, nvm

I'm experiencing one issue with the nvm in my windows 10 system while trying to install a specific node version using it using git bash. Please find the below screen attached.
[image]

Please find below the error I'm getting:

```
$ nvm install v12.18.3
Can not determine how many core(s) are available, running in single-threaded mode.
Please report an issue on GitHub to help us make nvm run faster on your computer!
Local cache found: ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3.tar.xz
Checksums match! Using existing downloaded archive ${NVM_DIR}/.cache/src/node-v12.18.3/node-v12.18.3.tar.xz
$>./configure --prefix=/c/Users/Subhojit/.nvm/versions/node/v12.18.3 <
which: no python2.7 in (/c/Users/Subhojit/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Subhojit/bin:%PYTHON%:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/cmd:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/Subhojit/bin/win-sudo/s)
which: no python2 in (/c/Users/Subhojit/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/Subhojit/bin:%PYTHON%:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/iCLS:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin:/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/cmd:/c/Program Files/NVIDIA Corporation/NVIDIA NvDLISR:/c/Program Files/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Roaming/nvm:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/c/Users/Subhojit/bin/win-sudo/s)
./configure: line 3: /c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied
./configure: line 3: /c/Users/Subhojit/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python: Permission denied
nvm: install v12.18.3 failed!
```

Any help regarding the issue would be appreciated!

Comment: Is there anything in particular that you do not understand about the error message?

Comment: I installed the python 2.7 again but still getting the same issue!